# FindHomography algorithm in OpenCV 3.1 : bug?

Tags: algorithm, opencv

I have some doubt about FindHomography algorithm. I wrote a program to test it. In this program I have rotated an image look for descriptors in original image and rotated image. After matching I use findHomography to retrieve transformation and calculate square error for RANSAC, LMEDS and RHO method. I wrote algorithm for Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm (using Numerical Recipes ). I can add some noise to point location. NR algorithm is best without noise. Problem is when noise increase. NR is always best and other algorithms (RANSAC LMEDS and RHO) become completly wrong. I fit only six parameters using NR. I think it is like in findHomography (see original post).
 Everybody can check my code here. If you want to check with NR you can download full code on github

Is my code good (see [enter link description here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/93559/findhomography-algorithm-some-doubt/))? Why opencv results are always worst than my code?

PS Original post is answers.opencv.org with three links and this title
FindHomography algorithm : some doubt